# Trace single request from start to finish in Django / Python

Tags: python, django

Is there a way in Django to uniquely trace a single request from start to finish? Specifically. I'd like to know that the request in BeforeViewMiddleware is the same as the one in ResponseMiddleware.

Currently I use request.session:

```
# executes at start of processing
class BeforeViewMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        id = insert_data_into_table()
        request.session["id"] = id

# executes when all processing is done
class ResponseMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # Match the request with the request in BeforeViewMiddleware
        id = request.session["id"]
        update_table(id)
```

However, this fails if two or more requests are made from the same session at about the same time. It then become race conditions where the one that started first might finish last and the IDs get mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a concrete attribute on the request itself:

```
class BeforeViewMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        id = ...
        request._unik_attr = id

class ResponseMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        id = request._unik_attr
        # ...
```

The request object, unlike the session, lives only for a single request-repsonse-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Storing your `id` value in the session can't work, because as you realized, there's only one session per user, regardless of the number of concurrent requests.

A better way to do this is to store the data in a thread local variable.  Each request is handled by the same thread from beginning to end, so the data sticks with the request.

```
from threading import local
_thread_data = local()

class BeforeViewMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        _thread_data.my_id = insert_data_into_table()

class ResponseMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        update_table(_thread_data.my_id)
```

Comment: Typically, you only require thread local magic in django when you have no access to the request, e.g. in a model method. But in the middleware, you have the request object which is the designated place to hold cycle-specific information.

Comment: You are right.. in this case your answer is better.  In my systems, I'm already using the same thread local object for a lot of my middleware needs (where often, I need to access that data from places where the request is not available), so once I am storing some life cycle data there, it makes sense for me to store all of it there.